# Crontab send email to root and postmaster

Tags: email, cron

I'm on a fresh server and I added (few days ago) a line in my `crontab -e`.

Since that, each time the cron is running, my server try to send an email to root (my gmail) and to an email like `postmaster@my_server.my_ip`.

My problem is emails sent to root (my gmail) are ok, but emails sent to `postmaster@my_server.my_ip` are all delayed, and I receive **A LOT** of emails from Mail Delivery Subsystem  like :

- Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed ....

It looks like gmail cannot sent email to `postmaster@...`

My questions :

- Why cron send emails to root and postmaster each time ? I did not do anything for that.
- How can I disable that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was answered previously [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26980/can-i-change-the-default-mail-recipient-on-cron-jobs).

Basically either change the `MAILTO=root` option in the crontab config to globally disable it, or pipe each job to null to stop it generating an email: `>/dev/null 2>&1`.